# How to get response from AngularJS $http.get().then()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've recently started to upgrade from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4, and that requires I also upgrade from AngularJS 1.5.8 to a minimum of AngularJS 1.6.1. I have a simple AngularJS/MVC application with the following code setup:

/scripts/app.js (contains routing)
/scripts/controllers.js (contains controllers, method calls, etc)
/scripts/services.js (contains the callback methods that hit the C# controllers and bring back data, or "do things" (CRUD methods)

In my controllers.js, I have a method:

```
function init() {
    api.initialIndexLoad(
        function(result) {
            if (result.error) {
                notificationService.danger("<h5>An error occurred.</h5><h6>Details: {0}</h6>".format(result.error));
            } else {
                vm.dataList = result.theDataFromCSharp;
            }
            vm.loaded = true;
        }
    );
}

init();
```

This makes a call to my services.js, where I have this code:

```
"use strict";

angular
.module("CustList.services", ["ngResource"])
.service("api",
    function api($resource, $http, notificationService) {
        function handleError(err, fn) {
            if (!fn) {
                notificationService.error(err);
            } else {
                fn(err);
            }
        }

        return {
            initialIndexLoad: function(callback, error) {
                $http.get("/Customers/InitialIndexLoad")
                    .success(callback)
                    .error(function(e) {
                        handleError(e, error);
                    });
            }
        };
    }
);
```

So, of course, after updating my libraries to AngularJS 1.6.1 (Actually, I went straight to AngularJS 1.7.5), I started to get errors, and after a while figured out that the promise syntax had changed. So I tried to change with it, and updated my services.js to be:

```
"use strict";

angular
.module("CustList.services", ["ngResource"])
.service("api",
    function api($resource, $http, notificationService) {
        function handleSuccess(response) {
            return response.data;
        }

        function handleError(err, fn) {
            if (!fn) {
                notificationService.error(err);
            } else {
                fn(err);
            }
        }

        return {
            initialIndexLoad: function() {
                $http
                    .get("/Customers/InitialIndexLoad")
                    .then(handleSuccess)
                    .catch(handleError);
            }
        };
    }
);
```

The errors went away, and I thought I had this upgrade licked, until I realized: I wasn't actually getting the data back! That new `handleSuccess` method I'd created was getting the data in the response, but the `return response.data` wasn't returning the data back to my controllers.js method, so I could plug it into `vm.dataList`.

It doesn't throw an error - it just does nothing. I'd appreciate help figuring this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service method needs to [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) the `$http` promise.

```
app.service("api",
    function api($http, notificationService) {
        function handleSuccess(response) {
            return response.data;
        }

        function handleError(err) {
            notificationService.error(err);
            throw err;
        }

        return {
            initialIndexLoad: function() {
                ̶$̶h̶t̶t̶p̶
                return $http
                    .get("/Customers/InitialIndexLoad")
                    .then(handleSuccess)
                    .catch(handleError);
            }
        };
    }
);
```

Notice that the `errorHandler` needs to [re-throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) the error. Otherwise the handler will *convert* the rejected promise to a fulfilled promise.

The controller needs to use the `.then` and `.catch` methods:

```
function init() {
    var promise = api.initialIndexLoad();
    promise.then(function(result) {
       if (result.error) {
            notificationService.danger("<h5>An error occurred.</h5><h6>Details: {0}</h6>".format(result.error));
        } else {
            vm.dataList = result.theDataFromCSharp;
        }
        vm.loaded = true;
    }).catch(functions(err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    });
}
```

The `.then` method returns a *new promise* which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the `successCallback`, `errorCallback` (unless that value is a promise, in which case it is resolved with the value which is resolved in that promise using [promise chaining](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-promises-queues).

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - The Promise API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api)
- [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Return inside of initialIndexLoad

so

```
return $http
                    .get("/Customers/InitialIndexLoad")
                    .then(handleSuccess)
                    .catch(handleError);
```

Would guess this is it, maybe lost during refactor/upgrade.